# Style-checking only works inline, does not work with stylesheet

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have just started using Typescript with a fresh React Native project. I was looking into type-checking styles (following https://medium.com/@zvona/stylesheets-in-react-native-with-typescript-revisited-6b4ba0a899d2) but I do not get type warnings with stylesheets, only inline.

This does not give any warnings

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import AppStyles from '../../AppStyles';

interface Styles {
  root: ViewStyle;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create<Styles>({
  root: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  },
});

interface Props {}

const LandingScreen: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <Text>Welcome to the landing screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

While this works as I want it to (VSCode warns me about the textAlign in a ViewStyle )

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

interface Props {}

const LandingScreen: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ textAlign: 'left', backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
      <Text>Welcome to the landing screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Does this take more configuration in VSCode or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of how the type of [`StyleSheet.create`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f764e7d5b727818dfc56f87b9864d1ae25c610b0/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L5389) is defined:

```js
export function create<T extends NamedStyles<T> | NamedStyles<any>>(styles: T | NamedStyles<T>): T;
```

Here we can see that the argument `styles` may have the type `T` or `NamedStyles<T>`. `NamedStyles` is defined as:

```js
type NamedStyles<T> = { [P in keyof T]: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle };
```

The object you pass in does not match `T` (in this case `Styles`), however it *does* match `NamedStyles<T>` because `NamedStyles<Styles>` effectively means:

```js
NamedStyles<Styles> = { root: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle }
```

---

Apart from trying to get the types changed, I see two solutions to solve this...

#### Extract Variable

If you extract the styles into a separate variable with the proper type, TypeScript will check it:

```js
const stylesObject: Styles = {
    root: {
        textAlign: 'left',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
    },
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create<Styles>(stylesObject);
```

#### Alias Function

You could also create an alias of the `StyleSheet.create` function with different typing:

```js
type CreateStyles = <T extends NamedStyles<T>>(styles: T) => T;

export const createStyles: CreateStyles = StyleSheet.create;
```

And then import and use `createStyles` over all of your project instead of `StyleSheet.create`.

Comment: Perfect! I am going with extracting the variable. Sorry if this was a stupid question, I am new to TS. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. And no, this wasn't a stupid question at all :)